# Cloth simulation staying in plane

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm working on a bathroom interior, and I was trying to shape the shower curtain by following this tutorial:
[Modeling with Cloth Simulation in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYemC0j6Ag)

For some reason, after I selected the pinned verticies group, and ran the simulation, the cloth was affected by the pinned verticies, and also sagged, but all the movement was done in one plane, so there were no wrinkles.  How can I fix this?  Here is an image of one of my tests so you can see what is happening:

[image: incorrect cloth simulation]

Here are my Physics Settings (As far as I know, they are the same as what he has, and also, I have animated shape keys so that the cloth would fold).

[image: Physics Settings]

Here is the .blend:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Rj7h_MP4waeU5yc3ZyV0VZQlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you screenshot your cloth settings?

Comment: Do you have force fields?

Comment: @TARDISMaker Sure one second.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Okay, I did it.

Comment: @AnsonSavage check again your pinned group that only the top vertices are assigned

Comment: @Denis, Yep, they are! :)

Comment: Does that mean only the top are assigned? If that wasn't the problem, I would change the preset to silk. This won't be at all what your looking for, but it will show if the problem is the stiffness.

Comment: @TARDISMaker, Yes only the top verticies are assigned, and I already tried playing with the stiffness, but I'll try silk and see if that makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: But your shapekey is deforming the whole fabric, not the top vertices

Comment: @TARDISMaker Nope, changing it to silk did not appear to make much of a difference.

Comment: Okay, can you upload a .blend than? I don't think anyone can really tell the answer here without playing with the scene your playing with. And it doesn't have to be the actual scene. As long as it shows off the problem it will work.

Comment: @Denis The shapekey is only animating the top verticies, but the entire cloth is being deformed because of the cloth physicis.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Sure, one second.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Okay, I did it.

Comment: Try activating self collision, and change and put the key frames closer together. I don't know exactly why it's doing what it's doing, but that seems to help for me.

Comment: Okay, I was just looking at a thread on the video where the person had the same problem.  It turns out that my problem was that I needed a new blender scene, and I needed to import it into my full blender scene.  It's working now.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Okay, that's weird. Why don't you answer you question so that this question can be put out of the way properly, and it because easier for other people to find the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24524/discussion-between-tardis-maker-and-anson-savage).

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I was trying to do a cloth simulation inside a scene with several objects already inside.  Many people had the same problem in the comments on this video:

[Modeling with Cloth Simulation in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYemC0j6Ag)

The trick was to do the cloth sim in a different scene and then import the mesh into the scene you want to use it in.

Comment: Too many collision objects in the Scene slowed the simulation down? I don't understand what the issue was.